# Folder "_catalogs" does not exist. error during SharePoint site collection UI upgrade

Tags: 2013, migration, web-application

I am migrating SharePoint 2010 web application to SharePoint 2013 using content database backup/restore approach. I have restored the database, mount database and then doing the site collection UI upgrade and it is failed with the "Folder '_catalogs' does not exist" error. I have tried "Fix it" button available in site collection health checks but that also throwing the same error (Screenshot below).

[image]

**I reviewed the Hive logs using the correlation Id and found below error messages**

> UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized.
>
> Application error when access /Misc/_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx, Error=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the folder is there in your SharePoint 2010 environment. If it is not there and someone, some how have deleted the folder, try to revert the folder with the revert function under sitesettings.

Comment: Magnus, If you are talking about "Reset to definition" under "Site Actions", I have already tried it but still the issue persists. Please let me know if you are talking about something different.